# Control line and legend colors in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following chart is exaclty as I want it to be, but I can only get this result by hardcoding the variable names inside the `geom_line` and `scale_color_manual` arguments.

Could I use ggplot2 to get this same result while having dynamic names for the lines in the chart legend?

Here is the code I`m using:

```
ggplot(weights_and_returns, aes(x = Date)) +
       geom_line(aes(y = ibov_rt_acc, color = "IBOV Index"), size = 1.0) +
       geom_line(aes(y = imab_rt_acc, color = "BZRFIMAB Index"), size = 1.0) +
       geom_line(aes(y = usdbrl_rt_acc, color = "USDBRL Curncy"), size = 1.0) +
       geom_line(aes(y = portfolio_rt_acc, color = "RP Portfolio"),  size = 1.0) +
       labs(y="Returns", 
            x = "Date", 
            title = "Risk parity - cumulative returns since 2Q2011") +
       scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 0.01)) +
       scale_color_manual(name = "Assets", 
                        values = c("IBOV Index" = "seagreen", 
                                   "BZRFIMAB Index" = "cyan", 
                                   "USDBRL Curncy" = "blueviolet",
                                   "RP Portfolio" = "blue")
                        )
```

and its output:

[image: chart]

Thank you.

Comment: You'd want to bring your data into long(er) form and then use the color aesthetic... i.e. `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(ggplot2); weights_and_returns %>% pivot_longer(-c(Date)) %>% ggplot(aes(Date, value, color = name)) + geom_line()` (assuming there are no other columns)

Comment: The key here was to understand ggplot is best used with the data in that longer format. I needed to subset my table and rename its columns before using pivor_longer. I now can give dynamic names to the series in the legend, but I'm not quite sure about how scale_color_manual associate the color names with the series.
Anyway, I lernned something today. Will read more about the concept of tidy data, which was what I was lacking in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: `scale_color_manual(values = c("#d11141", "#00b159"), breaks=c("ibov_rt_acc", "imab_rt_acc"))` etc. `breaks` argument can be omitted. There are also predefined lists of colors etc available (for a more automatic apporach). And for subsetting you can use `dplyr::select` which offers [many handy helper functions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.htmlhttps://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

(1) In your data, make a column that gives the color that you want the row to use as character values (e.g., the color name or Hexcode), then use `scale_color_identity()`--the line colors will be the given color.

(2) Specify `scale_color_manual()` and give values as an unnamed vector. Then, ensure that the variable in your data you are mapping to color is a factor, not character and that the levels are in the order you want.